# PlayFramework 2.0. Better way to build site with two parts

Tags: playframework-2.0

I started little project with Play Framework 2.0 and I wonder which is the better way for creating two-part site: admin and public? I want to make admin access over https protocol only.

Should I specify three sub-projects:

- Domain model project
- Public project
- Admin project

But even in this case I wonder how to specify access to admin part over https only?
Or this is possible to do in one project?

I've just found this: https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/d75cdb32d348dc0f/64838b04a452bfaf?lnk=raot which says that force HTTPS for some pages unavailable. Is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the HTTP or HTTPS access you can use a frontend HTTP server. I have used [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) for that.

Then, with Nginx (or [Lighthttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/)) you can use this frontend server to handle HTTPS for some urls (for example: www.mydomain.com/secure/*) and HTTP for others.

For admin access, you can do both: two independent projets or a single one. The first solution seams harder to maintain and will raise some questions about shared cache or sessions.

For both solutions you will need to have a look at proxy forwarding as your HTTP/HTTPS requests will be handled by your frontend server and then forwarded to your Play app(s).
Play documentation details [how to configure Lighthttpd for this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/HTTPServer).

Comment: Oh, great. Suddenly I understand that I can deal with two independent projects with common database. I don't think that is best solution. Solution with frontend HTTP servers looks like exactly what I need. Thanks.